# Rational to double and GCF

Tags: java, numbers, type-conversion, rational-numbers

This question is towards the last method. Whenever I return d in the method "public static Rational convert(double d)" it says that it can not convert from double to Rational. How would I make it so that I would be able to return a Rational number from the method without switching "Rational" to double or the parameter? And is that how I would implement a loop to find the GCF in the method as well, without creating another method?

```
public class Rational
{
// The state of a rational number is just the numerator and denominator.
private static int numerator;
private static int denominator;


// When created, a Rational's numerator and denominator are set.
public Rational( int num, int den )
{
    numerator = num;
    denominator = den;
}

// Accessor method for the numerator
public int getNumerator( )
{
    return numerator;
}

// Accessor method for the denominator
public int getDenominator( )
{
    return denominator;
}

// A mutator method which doubles the given rational number by doubling the
// numerator.
public void doubleNumber( )
{
    numerator *= 2;
}

// A method which returns the common denominator between the current and
// given rational.  Specifically, returns the denominator multiplied by the
// denominator of the given rational number.
public int findCommonDenominator( Rational r )
{
    return denominator * r.getDenominator( );
}

//Method returning the decimal value of the fraction.
public static double convert(Rational r)
{
    return (double) numerator / (double) denominator; 
}

//Method returning the smallest fraction possible from a decimal given. 
public static Rational convert(double d)
{
  d = (Math.floor(d * 100)/100);

  while ( denominator != 0)
  {
      d = (double) (numerator % denominator);
      numerator = denominator;
      d = (double) (denominator);
  }

  return d;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will probably never end. You never change the value of denominator.

Now, for the method `public static Rational convert(double d)`

You're returning a double, how does Java know that you want d to be a Rational?

It doesn't.

In that method you should be doing a return closer to:

```
Rational converted = new Rational(numerator, denominator);
return converted;
```

But before you do that you have to initialize both in the method.

You have a lot of work to do here.

1. You pass a `double d` to the method, then don't use the value, just overwrite it.
2. You have an endless loop in `while(denominator != 0)` because you never change denominators value.
3. I assume this method would be called as `Rational rational = Rational.convert(someDouble);` So you should consider declaring a numerator and denominator inside of the method, and returning something like `new Rational(num,dem);`